# Show that the set $K(v,{1\over 2}(w+y))\cap K(w,{1\over 2}(v+y)) \cap K(y,{1\over 2}(v+w))$ is nonempty, and determine how many elements it can have.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence

Let $V$ be a vector space  over $\mathbb{R}$. For vectors $v\neq w$ in $V$, let $K(v,w)$ be the set of all vectors in $V$ of the form $(1-a)v+aw$, where $0\leq a\leq 1$. Given vectors $v,w,y\in V$ satisfying the condition that the set $\{w-v, y-v\}$ is linearly independent (and so, in particular, its elements are distinct), show that the set $K(v,{1\over 2}(w+y))\cap K(w,{1\over 2}(v+y)) \cap K(y,{1\over 2}(v+w))$ is nonempty, and determine how many elements it can have.

I'm trying to determine the number of elements in this set. Any hints or solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The vector $(1/3)(v + y + w)$ is in your intersection. (Why?) Can there be any other vectors?

Comment: I don't see why. Did you let $a$ be a fixed value?

Comment: @DerpMagoo Try setting the weight $a$ for the single vector to be $1/3$ and the weight for the average of the other two vectors to be $2/3$.

Comment: I let $a={2\over 3}$ and then the three set all have the same elements, that is, ${1\over 3}(v+y+w)$.

Comment: Can I let $a={1\over n}$ and generalize this? That way $a$ will always be in the desired interval and the set is nonempty and infinite?

Comment: @DerpMagoo Exactly. Now the only part left is determining whether anything else can be in the intersection. Your linear independence assumption will come in handy for that.

Comment: No, in general if you choose different $a$ you might not get the same resulting vector for your different sets.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean about that, as for the linear independence part, how exactly do I use that assumption to show if the intersection contains more elements?